# how to cancel click event in onTouch method?

Tags: android, onclick, click

I need to create a `Button` which can be dragged across the screen. I already tried to set `clickable` to false by calling `setClickable(false)` in ACTION_MOVE but that did not work. Thanks for any helpful answer.

Here is my `onTouch()` method:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            //here is click or drag is not sure. we return false here.
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            //here after 2~3 events come. we known it's click or drag( by calculate the distance). question here: if current status is drag, how to cancel the click event? 
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        default:;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by cancel the click event? You can just consume the click event and do nothing by only returning `true`.

Comment: @Xaver Kapeller , i think consume the click event is not a good idea. because it's depend on system's setting(have Key Sound or Key Shock ).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, what about this depends on the systems settings? You cannot undo what has already happened, if you get a touch event you cannot prevent it from occurring, it has already happened. If you don't want other views to know about this touch event you have to prevent it from ever reaching them by consuming it yourself. There is no way around that. The only way for the touch event to no count as a click is by consuming the touch event yourself.